# redirect non www to www with URI with mod_rewrite.c

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can anyone help me with above situations:

1, http to https

all access must be changed to https://~

2, 4subdomains in 1 host(www and ex1~3)

www.example.com, ex1.example.com, ex2.example.com, ex3.example.com

3, no subdomain redirects to www with URIs

https://example.com/dir/ must be changed to https://www.example.com/dir/

I have this rewrite.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

right now I'm having https://example.com/dir/ be https://www.example.com, and not getting a solution to this.

Hope someone would help me with this problem.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ex1|ex2|ex3)\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Server version: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix),
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03

Answer (score 0):

The 1st Rule is being processed as [Last] and isn't reaching the 2nd rule to redirect htts://example.com/dir/ to the www. version. Try switching them around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ex1|ex2|ex3)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Also, you can't use a preceding slash in apache 2. You should remove it as I did above or optional match it if apache 1 is ever used:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Also, I would recommend making all the redirect flags [R=302] until you confirm they are working to prevent caching issues on redirects.